# Jquery - Menu mouse over on <a> not <a> <span>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am hacking the following menu on this page: http://cssmenumaker.com/menu/slabbed-accordion-menu

I want to to expand on hover so that I can have a link on the top level menu item as well as the expanded items.

I have the following code in my script that works on hover and on the mobile when tapped.

```
( function( $ ) {
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('#cssmenu li.has-sub > a ').on('mouseover', function(){
    $(this).removeAttr('');
    var element = $(this).parent('li');
    if (element.hasClass('open')) {
        element.removeClass('open');
        element.find('li').removeClass('open');
        element.find('ul').slideUp();
    }
    else {
        element.addClass('open');
        element.children('ul').slideDown();
        element.siblings('li').children('ul').slideUp();
        element.siblings('li').removeClass('open');
        element.siblings('li').find('li').removeClass('open');
        element.siblings('li').find('ul').slideUp();
    }
});
```

The issue I have is that when the mouse pointer hovers over the 'li.has-sub a' it expands fine, but it also triggers again when the 'li.has-sub a span' is hovered over. How can I prevent the  within the link also triggering the event?

This is the html:

```
<ul>
 <li><a href='#'><span>Home</span></a></li>
  <li class='active has-sub'><a href='index.html'><span>Serviced Apartments</span></a>
  <ul>
  <li><a href='#'><span>Submenu 1</span></a></li>
  <li><a href='#'><span>Submenu 2</span></a></li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li><a href='#'><span>Find/Contact Us</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Show css how `li.has-sub`, `a` and `span` are styled.

Answer (score 0):

i think problem lies with how you define var element because

```
var element = $(this).parent('li');
```

shows anchor tag and span both are child of li so $(this) can be defined as 'a' and 'span'

best solution remove span i don't think they are in use

Answer (score 0):

Try making things simpler for yourself, is this what you wanted to do ?

http://jsfiddle.net/prn3gtqb/

```
<ul id="cssmenu">
<li><a href='#'><span>Home</span></a></li>
..</ul>
```

Comment: you forgot to give ul an id